# Best practice to add/show select options dynamically JS/jquery/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

I would like to ask you what is best practice for dynamically generating select options using PHP, javascript and jquery.

For example - car bazaar - client has to choose car brand and after that web app has to  **add**/**show** car model options only for that car brand.

Techniques that I can think of and I consider :

- Call backend via JS everytime after user selects car brand, backend will return all car models for that brand and I then I can add them to select via JS/jquery
- Load all car models from backend with first page initialization, load them to JS variable and then everytime after user selects car brand add models options to select
- Load all car models from backend with first page initialization, add all model options to select via PHP with style="display:none" class="car_brand" attributes and after user selects car brand search all options with class="selected_car_brand" and remove style="display:none" from them

What are you using for problems like this and how do you work with dynamic select options?

Thanks guys! Have a nice day.

Comment: I would send the entire data set to the client on the first page load, and then perform all the visual manipulations in JS on the client side. It's a small amount of data and it almost never changes, so it doesn't make much sense to repeatedly hit the server for it.

Comment: If amount of data by structure is not complex and easy to get from base (simple requests) and scenario is very predictive, one can load it at once. If it is complex and it is hard fo you to guess user scenario conduct, you load it via ajax dynamicaly (and build buttons, select lists, options, checkboxes etc.) Repeated unecessary creation of too branched datasctucture may be an overkill to traffic or to database or just a bottleneck with each hit of page.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many car brands and models you have.
If you have 1k products, I would do call backend via JS every time after the user selects the car brand, if you have 100 products, you might just want to call the backend once and get all data and show what you want to show.

The best practice depends on your project.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on several factors like latency tolerance vs. throttling.

But the best answer if you are just starting out is probably is to call the backend every time.

The reason for this is that in real life in production, the values of car brands, models and quantity available are going to be changing all the time. So your best best is to continually get the most recent information.